# iPhone Centering Vertically Problems

Tags: android, iphone, css, media-queries, centering

Struggling to center my wrapper div vertically on iphone - in additional getting content cut off on android. First time i've tried to modify a site to work on phones and it's far from fun.

```
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){

 #triggers {
margin: 5% auto 0;
position: static;
width: 850px;
height: 500px;
top:50%;
z-index: 1;
display:none;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 80 % Height and 10% on top

Comment: didn't seem to work - is there any standardisation around this or just trial and error? or something I should change in the body/html css?

Comment: normally i use javascript. i take the height of the element and the height of the window and then i make top: (window height - element height) / 2; that is my standard for this kind of positioning. anyway you could try the same 80% plus top 10% but using position:absolute;